# help with simplifying Markov chains

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

1) $p(X_1)p(X_2|X_1)p(X_3|X_1, X_2)p(X_4|X_1, X_2, X_3)$

2) $p(X_4)p(X_3|X_4)p(X_2|X_3, X_4)p(X_1|X_2, X_3, X_4)$

For the first one, I got : $p(X_1)\,p(X_2|X_1)\,p(X_3\mid X_2)\,p(X_4\mid X_3)$ and for the second one, I got : $p(X_4)\,p(X_3\mid X_4)\,p(X_2\mid X_3)\,p(X_1\mid X_2)$.

I am not sure if this is correct so it would be appreciated to see if it is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrCyC.png)

Comment: HINT: The first one can be simplified further. Remember that $P(A)P(B|A) = P(A,B)$.

Comment: if i were to simplify it so that p(X1)p(X2|X1)  = p(X1,X2) would i still be able to draw that markov chain graphically?

Comment: Yes, it would just be $X_1 \to X_2$, right?

Comment: would the graph be  X1 → X2 → X3 → X4 for the first one and im not sure how the graph would look for the second one let alone if the second one is simplified correctly

Comment: Actually, probably the easiest way to do both is to use the definition of conditional probability and cancel out.

Comment: Yes to the first one. I don't think your second one is right. I can't get anything like that at least.

Comment: could you show me what you got since i have no idea how i would do the second one

Comment: Did you try using the definition of conditional probability?

Comment: p(X3,X4)p(X2∣X3)p(X1∣X2) is what i got

Comment: If I use the definition, I get for example: $P(X_2|X_3,X_4)=\frac{P(X_2,X_3,X_4)}{P(X_3,X_4)}$. Doing this for all the terms, a lot(!) of stuff cancels out.

Comment: ill try it now however i might need  to link a picture of my attempt since i wont be able to write it

Comment: By the way, if you need to draw a picture illustrating the two scenarios (which it sounds like you do?), the second one would be "working backwards". I.e. Start with $X_4$. Then what is the prob. that we came from $X_3$? What is the prob. that we then came from $X_2$ and so on.

Comment: i still get the same answer i got at the start and im not sure what im doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

For the second one:
$$
P(X_4)\cdot P(X_3|X_4)\cdot P(X_2|X_3, X_4)\cdot P(X_1|X_2, X_3, X_4) \\
= P(X_4) \cdot \frac{P(X_3,X_4)}{P(X_4)}
\cdot \frac{P(X_2,X_3,X_4)}{P(X_3,X_4)}
\cdot \frac{P(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)}{P(X_2,X_3,X_4)} \\
P(X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4)
$$

The first one can be simplified in the same way.

You may also be right, I'm not really sure. If you think you are right, you could show me how you got your answer?

Comment: i think im not meant to simplify the factorisation on the markov chain and i will link the question so you can see it

Comment: Actually, I think your answer is also correct. I didn't realise the Markov property works in reverse. (I don't remember learning that...). But you can fiddle around with the usual property to get the reverse one. I am sorry.

Comment: Well, it says you have to simplify, doesn't it? Then you can decide which ones of our simplifications you like best. I'm pretty sure your answers are right.